# Excel 2010 COUNTIF(): The formula you typed contains an error

Tags: windows, excel-formula, excel-2010

This thing is breaking my head. Please, take a look and get me out a solution !

[image]

1. tried using (comma (,) ) instead of ;
2. tried using this  ==COUNTIF($J$2:$j$51;"<40")

my-setup  :
platform : windows 7
application name : Microsoft excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

The formula looks fine. You may have an issue with your regional/language settings.

To view or modify your language settings within Excel, go to File > Options > Language.